# Why MATLAB keeps getting error 'Unrecognized Variable' when i pass a matrix of numbers?

Tags: matlab

My code is :

```
function qam = qmodulation(t, Fc, symbol)

   modcombs = [      
         1 1;        
         1 3;
         3 1;
         3 3;
         -1 1;
         -1 3;
         -3 1;
         -3 3;
         -1 -1;
         -1 -3;
         -3 -1;
         -3 -3;
         1 -1;
         1 -3;
         3 -1;
         3 -3;
        ];

   for j = 1:16
       if(symbol == (j-1))
           i = modcombs(j,1);
           q = modcombs(j,2);
       end
   end

   qam = cos(2*pi*Fc*t).*i - sin(2*pi*Fc*t).*q ;

end
```

I have one more function called "symbol( t , tinc , csn , bits )":

```
function sym = symbol(t, tinc, csn, bits)
      
   qamx = 16;
   digitcount = log(qamx)/log(2);
   compfact = 1/tinc;
   
   tsyc = 20000/digitcount;                
   sampleperiod = csn/tsyc;                
   bitindex = digitcount*fix( (t*compfact) / sampleperiod ) + 1 ;
   
   temp = 0;

   for k = 0 : 1 : ( digitcount - 1 )         
       temp = temp + bits(bitindex) * 2.^(digitcount-1-k);
       bitindex = bitindex + 1;
   end
   sym = temp;

end
```

This is main script:

```
tmin = 0;
tinc = 0.0000001;
tmax = 3.9999999;
csn = (tmax - tmin + tinc) / tinc;                        
bits = round(0.75*rand(1,20000)); 

t = tmin : tinc : tmax;        
Fc = 50000;                     
y = qmodulation( t, Fc, symbol(t, tinc, csn, bits) );
%y = awgn(x,35,'measured');
plot(t,y)
```

I want to modulate the `qmodulation` function with symbol function. But when i pass the symbol function into `qmodulation`, MATLAB doesn't seems to get the symbol function and can't enter the `if` block in the `qmodulation` function. Thus, `i` and `q` are not defined. So the command window shows an error "Unrecognized Variable 'i'".

When I pass a single value as symbol parameter, `qmodulation` function works fine and MATLAB can plot it.

All the parameters are defined in the main function. `tmin`, `tinc`, `tmax` also predefined.

```
t = tmin : tinc : tmax;   

qmodulation( t , Fc , 15 ) --->  Works fine

qmodulation( t , Fc , symbol( t , tinc , csn , bits ) ) ---> Doesn't work, Unrecognized Error

qmodulation ( t , Fc , symbol( 0.080 , tinc , csn , bits ) ) ---> Works fine too
```

What could possible cause that? Why MATLAB doesn't seem to get a matrix of data while it's okey with a single value?

The Error is :

```
>> main
Unrecognized function or variable 'i'.

Error in qmodulation (line 34)
   qam = cos(2*pi*Fc*t).*i - sin(2*pi*Fc*t).*q ;

Error in main (line 12)
y = qmodulation( t, Fc, symbol(t, tinc, csn, bits) );
```

Comment: What does `symbol( t , tinc , csn , bits )` return? Is that correct and what you expected? If so, the `symbol` call is unrelated to your question, and you could remove all of that from the post and make things simpler for folks here to understand. You could ask why `qmodulation( t , Fc , 15 )` works fine but `qmodulation( t , Fc , [15,16,17] )` doesn't. See [mre]. Also, please include the full error message, so we understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: The `for j = 1:16` loop in `qmodulation` can be simply written as `j = symbol+1; i = modcombs(j,1); q = modcombs(j,2);`. If you do that, you might see that `qmodulation` now works with an array as input. Because what is `symbol == (j-1)` if `symbol` is an array?

Comment: Thanks you, problem solved. This time, i have a memory problem. Any suggestions making this more efficient ?

Comment: Your `t` is huge. Try a smaller one. You could run your `qmodulation` over parts of `t` to reduce memory use.